# Application of Green's theorem, free electron model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration

I am just reading [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1699299) about a free electron model in conjugated molecules and got a bit confused about equation (1.38).

There is an integral:
$$
\int_0^{a_B}
   f_B(x_B) \left(\frac{d}{d x_B}\right)^2 g_B(x_B)
   - \left(f_B(x_B) \frac{d}{d x_B}\right)^2 g_B(x_B)
\, d x
$$
Using Green's theorem this should give:
$$
\left[
   f_B(x_B) \frac{d}{d x_B} g_B(x_B)
   - f_B(x_B) \frac{d}{d x_B} g_B(x_B)
\right]_0^{a_B}
$$

I don't know how to make this conversion using Green's theorem. Especially because the appearing functions should be one-dimensional and the equality can be straightforwardly proven using integration by parts.

Could you tell me why and how Green's theorem should be applied here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green's theorem *is* integration by parts.

Comment: Wow, that is a really good example of a false friend. I am German and "Satz von Green" only refers to the 2D version with path integrals etc.. So I thought there is some shenanigan involved with using higher dimensions etc.